# Change attribute from data-src to src WITHOUT jQuery

Tags: javascript, attributes

I am building a lightbox, in pure JavaScript. I currently have my images loading via AJAX, but i know it is easier to just have the img data-src attribute being replaced onclick to src.

I however have NO idea how this is done in pure JavaScript, by that i mean, without using any libraries.

Can anyone tell me how this is done?

to sum up: How do i change ex:

```
<img data-src="URL"/>
```

to:

```
<img src="URL"/>
```

without jQuery.

Comment: On what action do you want to change this?

Comment: Just wanted to make a listner for a click. But i got the answer now below :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it like shown below:

```
var imgEl = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i<imgEl.length; i++) {
    if(imgEl[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
       imgEl[i].setAttribute('src',imgEl[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
       imgEl[i].removeAttribute('data-src'); //use only if you need to remove data-src attribute after setting src
    }
}
```

The above code will fetch all `img` tags, check if they have a `data-src` attribute and if present, **replace** it with `src`.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RzB8P/)

Answer (score 7):

Get a handle on the image element, and then set it's `src` property, using the value from `getAttribute()`.

Plain Javascript doesn't have any helper functions to handle `data-*` attributes, it just treats them as any other attribute.

```
var img = document.getElementById("myimg");
img.src = img.getAttribute("data-src");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forEach` with `querySelectorAll`

```js
var imageElements = document.querySelectorAll('img');
   
imageElements.forEach(c=> c.setAttribute('src',c.getAttribute('data-src')));
```

```css
img{width:100px;}
```

```html
<img data-src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nature-20/512/79-512.png' />
```